# How to prevent Boostrapvalidator from disabling all buttons on a form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using boostrapvalidator from nghuuphuoc and I've this situation, when the validation is fired all my buttons are disabled. This is a problem to me because I want a specific button to be skipped from the validation. Is there anyway of doing this using the validator?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem where wants to keep two buttons alive if form has invalid field(s).

Figured out **Three** possible solutions.

> By default, the submit button(s) will be disabled if there is at least one invalid field

Minimal generic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8x76oLwu/) having multiple buttons disabled if form field(s) invalid.

**Solution-1**

Change the other button's type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` will keep the other buttons alive and only disable the submit button if form  field(s) invalid.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x76oLwu/1/)

---

**Solution-2**

Add attribute `name="submitme"` *only* to form `submit` button and define it in  `bootstrapvalidator` plugin call.
*Important:* Do not use attribute `name="submit"` if you do the submit button will remain [disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/8x76oLwu/2/) even if field(s) will be valid.

Note: in this solution, all buttons have `type="submit"`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selector').bootstrapValidator({
        submitButtons: 'button[name="submitme"]',
        // Rest of the validation code goes here
    });
});
```

This will only disable the `submit` button and keep the other buttons alive if form field(s) invalid.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x76oLwu/3/)

---

**Solution-3**

Use form event `status.field.bv` and check if form field(s) valid or not keep the other button's alive

Note: This solution tested and will work with new version `0.5.3`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selector').bootstrapValidator({
        // Rest of the validation code goes here
    }).on('status.field.bv', function (e, data) {
        formIsValid = true; 
        if(formIsValid) { 
            $('#cancel').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#reset').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: Added `id's` to button(s) which needs to be alive if form field(s) invalid.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x76oLwu/5/)